# Few questions about info program

Tags: info

I have a problem with some commands in info.

1. I found that C-x means not C but Ctrl.
2. In addition I have a problem with "M-x" (this is probably not "M"
   key (shift+m), and RET is the Enter key??
3. There is also "LFD     (select-reference-this-line)" and I have no idea which key is that.

Comment: Strange, only old timers knows how the answers. I’m still using emacs but didn’t used info in this century.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `C` and `M` is given in [the section on moving the cursor](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Cursor-Commands.html) in the `info` manual:

> *`C-x`* means press the *`CTRL`* key and the key *x*. *`M-x`* means press the *`META`* key and the key *x*. On many terminals the *`META`* key is known as the *`ALT`* key.

`M-x` shortcuts can also be invoked by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>x</kbd>.

LFD is less obvious; that’s “line feed”, aka <kbd>Return</kbd> (or <kbd>⏎</kbd> typically). See [the entry for `select-reference-this-line`](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Selecting-Xrefs.html#index-select_002dreference_002dthis_002dline) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct, `C-x` is shorthand for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>.  This however you have presented as a statement and it unclear how this is a "problem".
2. Firstly: Similarly, `M-x` is shorthand for <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>.  The <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is usually mapped to <kbd>L-Alt</kbd>.  Secondly: You are correct; `RET` is shorthand for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  This is due to historical stylings: the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on a modern keyboard is where the Carriage Return (hence "Return") key was on slightly modern typewriters.  Some computer peripheral manufacturers (e. g. Apple) decided to stick with this nomenclature, while others (e. g. IBM) re-defined the key as the key used to "Enter" data into the system, since a terminal did not have a carriage to actually Return.
3. `LFD` is shorthand for "linefeed", which is the (or *one of the*, depending on your environment's line-ending preference) character(s) generated by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, which on some keyboard layouts is styled as <kbd>Return</kbd> (which in turn why `RET` is shorthand for the <kbd>Return</kbd> key).